# show that $L=\{a^*\}\cup\{b^ja^{n^2}|0<j,1\leq n \}$ Holds the pumping lemma for context-free languages

Tags: automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

prove this language verifies the conclusion of the pumping lemma

> show that $L=\{a^*\}\cup\{b^ja^{n^2}|0<j,1\leq n \}$

> Holds the pumping lemma for context-free languages

the problem is that I know how to refute with pumping lemma that a language is **not context-free**.
but I don't know how to prove Language holds the pumping lemma -> **is a context-free** lang.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What does "holds the pumping lemma" mean?

Comment: We discourage posts that are just the statement of an exercise-like task and a request for us to solve it.  What did you try? What progress have you made?  Where did you get stuck?  Where did you encounter this task? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: the problem is that I know how to refute with pumping lemma that a language is **not context-free**.
but I don't know how to prove Language holds the pumping lemma -> **is a context-free** lang.

Comment: The question means "prove this language verifies the conclusion of the pumping lemma", it does not mean that the language is context-free (it is not). Such an exercice can hold as a proof that the reciprocal of the pumping lemma is false.

Comment: i tried to edit the question so it will describe the problem better, my english is bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can never prove a language to be context-free with the use of pumping lemma alone. The pumping lemma for context-free languages states a property that is necessary but not sufficient for context-free languages. There are no context-free languages that lack a context-free pumping property, but there are languages that have this property despite not being context-free.

Let $s \in L$ with $|s| \geq p$ for some pumping length $p$ of $L$. I am going to show that for any such $s$, the $uvwxy$ division required by the pumping lemma is possible. Due to the definition of $L$, we know that one of the following is true:

1. $s = a^n$ for some $n \geq p$
2. $s = b^ma^n$ for some $m \geq 1$ and $n$ is a natural square

For each of these cases, there exists a trivial decomposition that satisfies the conditions of the pumping lemma. Can you find them?

Note that in the end, $L$ is not context-free, so this will serve as a proof of non-invertibility of the pumping lemma – you cannot use it to prove a language context-free.

Comment: thank you ! a lot really